# Problem in bounding box collision detection in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

I have a Background class containing 5 layers, I've created a collision box for 5th layer. Here is the code for my `Background` class:

```
package com.gitlab.runner.tiger;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.gitlab.runner.tiger.utilities.ParallaxBackground;
import com.gitlab.runner.tiger.utilities.ParallaxLayer;

/**
 * Created by Pintu on 4/17/2017.
 */
public class Background extends AbstractGameObject {

    private World world;
    ParallaxLayer l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6;
    ParallaxBackground bg;

    final float bgSpeed = 10f;
    //collison box for 5th layer
    Rectangle hitBox, nextHitBox;


    public Background(float x, float y, float width, float height, World world) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.world = world;
        //creating parallax layer(region,parallaxRatio,padding)
        l1 = new ParallaxLayer(Assets.bgLayerRegion1, bgSpeed, 0);
        l2 = new ParallaxLayer(Assets.bgLayerRegion2, 4, 0);
        l3 = new ParallaxLayer(Assets.bgLayerRegion3, 3, 0);
        l4 = new ParallaxLayer(Assets.bgLayerRegion4, 2, 0);
        l5 = new ParallaxLayer(Assets.bgLayerRegion5, 1, 0);
        l6 = new ParallaxLayer(Assets.bgLayerRegion6, bgSpeed, 0);
        ParallaxLayer[] layers = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6};
        bg = new ParallaxBackground(layers, world.getCamera());

        hitBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, World.GAME_WIDTH, 12.5f);
        nextHitBox = new Rectangle(hitBox.x+World.GAME_WIDTH,0, World.GAME_WIDTH, 12.5f);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
        scrolling(delta);
    }

    //Scrolls the background across the screen
    private void scrolling(float delta) {
        //Moving camera
        //posBck2 =0,posBck2=at width of bg

        //posBck2 = (int) (posBck1 + width);
        // if (world.getCamera().position.x >= (posBck2 + world.getCamera().viewportWidth / 2)) {
        //   posBck1 = posBck2;
        //}
        hitBox.x = l5.positionX;
        hitBox.y = l5.positionY;
        nextHitBox.x = hitBox.x + World.GAME_WIDTH;
        hitBox.y = l5.positionY;
        world.getCamera().position.x += bgSpeed * delta;
        bg.moveX(1f * delta);


    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
       /* for (TextureRegion layer : layers
                ) {

            batch.draw(layer, posBck1, y, width, height);
        }
        for (TextureRegion layer : layers
                ) {

            batch.draw(layer, posBck2, y, width, height);
        }*/
        bg.render(batch);


    }

    public void drawDebug(ShapeRenderer renderer) {

        renderer.rect(hitBox.getX(), hitBox.getY(), hitBox.getWidth(), hitBox.getHeight());
        renderer.rect(nextHitBox.getX(), nextHitBox.getY(), nextHitBox.getWidth(), nextHitBox.getHeight());

    }


}
```

Here is the code for the `Player` class:

```
package com.gitlab.runner.tiger;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;

/**
 * Created by Pintu on 4/19/2017.
 */
public class Player extends AbstractGameObject {
    //Player Phyics Variable(acceleration,position,speed,gravity)
    final float ACC = 0.046875f * 10;
    final float FRC = 0.046875f * 10;
    final int TOP = 20;
    float GRAVITY = -0.21875f * 5;
    float xsp;
    //Test textureRegion
    TextureRegion texture;
    Animation<TextureRegion> run;
    TextureAtlas playerAtlas;
    //StateTime to keep track of animation frame
    float stateTime = 0;

    //gettter ,setters
    public float getPositionX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void stopGravity() {
        GRAVITY=0;
    }

    //enum states from each animation
    enum State {
        RUNNING
    }

    //currentState to keep track of current animation
    State currentState = State.RUNNING;

    //Constructor
    public Player(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        texture = Assets.playerRegion;
        playerAtlas = Assets.playerAtlas;
        //Initialise Animation using frames
        run = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1 / 4f, playerAtlas.getRegions(), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);


    }

    //Update and Draw code
    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
        if (delta == 0)
            return;
        stateTime += delta;
        //Player Run pyhsics
       /* if (xsp < TOP) {
            xsp += ACC;
        } else {
            xsp -= Math.min(Math.abs(xsp), FRC) * Math.signum(xsp);
        }*/

        setPosition(getX(), getY() + GRAVITY);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        //based on the state get animation frame
        TextureRegion region = null;
        switch (currentState) {
            case RUNNING:
                region = run.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                break;
        }

        batch.draw(region, getX(), getY(), width, height);

    }

    public void drawDebug(ShapeRenderer renderer) {
        renderer.rect(this.getBoundingRectangle().x, this.getBoundingRectangle().y, this.getBoundingRectangle().getWidth(), this.getBoundingRectangle().getHeight());
    }


}
```

In another `World` class, I'm checking the collisions between them but didn't get satisfying results. Here is the code for my `World` class:

```
package com.gitlab.runner.tiger;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;

/**
 * Created by Pintu on 4/17/2017.
 */
public class World {
    //Constants - GameWidth,GameHeight
    public static final int GAME_WIDTH = 100;
    public static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 100;
    float viewportWidth, viewportHeight;
    float aspectRatio;
    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    //All game object reference here
    public Background bg;
    public Player player;

    public World() {
        viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        aspectRatio = viewportHeight / viewportWidth;
        //setting up camera,camera width -half of game width,camera height - multiplied by aspect ratio;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT * aspectRatio);
        camera.position.set(GAME_WIDTH / 2, (aspectRatio / 2) * GAME_HEIGHT, 0);
        //All game object created here
        bg = new Background(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, this);
        player = new Player(100, 100f, 10, 10);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        //update camera every frame
        camera.update();
        //check collison

        checkCollision();
        player.setX(camera.position.x);
        //All game objects updated here
        bg.update(delta);
        player.update(delta);

    }

    private void checkCollision() {
        float oldX = player.getX(), oldY = player.getY();

        if (Intersector.overlaps(player.getBoundingRectangle(), bg.hitBox)) {
           // Gdx.app.log("TAG", bg.hitBox.y + bg.hitBox.getHeight() + ",");
            player.setPosition(bg.hitBox.x + bg.hitBox.getWidth(), bg.hitBox.y + bg.hitBox.getHeight());
            Gdx.app.log("TAG", "COLLISON");
        } else if (player.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(bg.nextHitBox)) {
            player.setPosition(bg.nextHitBox.x + bg.hitBox.getWidth(), bg.nextHitBox.y + bg.nextHitBox.getHeight());
        }

    }

    public OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting this

[image]

Please check my code to see if there is problem in my collision code or somewhere else. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, the player sprite is falling below the top of the ground bounding box? I think this is because your call to `player.update(delta)` causes the player to move down due to gravity. Try moving the call to `checkCollision()` after `player.update(delta)`.

Comment: @VictorT. ok i'll try

Answer (score -1):

Thanks!you for your guidance that was a silly mistake ,this is the right way.

```
//All game objects updated here
bg.update(delta);
 player.update(delta);
//Checks collision
checkCollision();
```